# Far-field Poynting vector for time varying source [check my math please]

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

This is a question from classical electrodynamics, but it's the maths of it I need some help in.

I have fields $\rho\left(\vec{r},t\right)$, $\vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t\right)$, $\vec{E}\left(\vec{r},t\right)$ and $\vec{B}\left(\vec{r},t\right)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The fields $\rho$ and $\vec{J}$ are related by the **Continuity Equation**:
$$
-\dfrac {\partial \rho (\vec{r}, t)} {\partial t} = \nabla \cdot \vec{J} (\vec{r}, t)
$$
Let us say $\mathbb{V}_s \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is the **smallest spherical volume** such that:
$$
\forall t, \qquad \forall \vec{r}\notin \mathbb{V}_s: \qquad\qquad \rho\left(\vec{r},t\right) = \vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t\right) = 0
$$
$$
\forall t, \qquad \forall \vec{r}\in \partial\mathbb{V}_s: \qquad\qquad \rho\left(\vec{r},t\right) = \vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t\right) = 0 
$$
Since $\mathbb{V}_s$ is a sphere, I say that its *center* is at $\vec{r}_0$, and its *diameter* id $\mathcal{D}$.

Now given the definitions:
$$
\vec{r}_s \in \mathbb{V}_s,\qquad
\vec{R} = \vec{r} - \vec{r}_s,\qquad
R=\left|\vec{R}\right|, \qquad
\hat{R}=\frac {\vec{R}} {R}, \qquad
t_r = t - \frac {R} {c}
$$
The fields $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ are as follows:
$$
\vec{E}\left(\vec{r},t\right) =
\frac {1} {4 \pi \epsilon_0}
\iiint_{\mathbb{V}_s} {\left[
\frac {\rho (\vec{r}_s, t_r)} {R^2} \hat{R} +
\frac {1} {R c} \frac {\partial \rho (\vec{r}_s, t_r) } {\partial t} \hat{R} -
\frac {1} {R c^2} \frac {\partial \vec{J} (\vec{r}_s, t_r) } {\partial t} \right]}
\space dV\left(\vec{r}_s\right)
$$
$$
\vec{B}\left(\vec{r},t\right) =
\frac {\mu_0} {4 \pi}
\iiint_{\mathbb{V}_s} {\left[
\frac {\vec{J}  (\vec{r}_s, t_r)} {R^2} \times \hat{R} +
\frac {1} {R c} \frac {\partial \vec{J}  (\vec{r}_s, t_r) } {\partial t} \times \hat{R} \right]}
\space dV\left(\vec{r}_s\right)
$$
(Physically, $\vec{E}$, $\vec{B}$. $\vec{J}$ & $\rho$ have the standard meanings from Electrodynamics. The equations above are the [Jefimenko's equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations))

Now the paper ["The Relation Between Expressions for Time-Dependent Electromagnetic Fields Given by Jefimenko and by Panofsky and Phillips"](http://puhep1.princeton.edu/~kirkmcd/examples/jefimenko.pdf) by Kirk T. McDonald shows that the expression for $\vec{E}$ can be transformed into:
$$
\scriptsize{
\vec{E}\left(\vec{r},t\right) =
\frac {1} {4 \pi \epsilon_0}
\iiint_{\mathbb{V}_s} {\left[
\frac {\rho (\vec{r}_s, t_r)} {R^2} \hat{R}
 + \frac 
      { \left(\vec{J} (\vec{r}_s, t_r) \cdot \hat{R}\right)\hat{R} + \left(\vec{J} (\vec{r}_s, t_r) \times\hat{R}\right) \times \hat{R} } 
      {R^2 c}
 + \frac {1} {R c^2} \left( \frac {\partial \vec{J} (\vec{r}_s, t_r) } {\partial t} \times \hat{R} \right) \times \hat{R}
\right]}
\space dV\left(\vec{r}_s\right)
}
$$
Now I want to compute the quantity $\vec{S}\left(\vec{r},t\right) = 
\dfrac {\vec{E}\left(\vec{r},t\right) \times \vec{B}\left(\vec{r},t\right)} {\mu_0}$ for $\vec{r}$ for which $R \gg \mathcal{D}$. I figured that for such values of $\vec{r}$, the maximum possible difference between the values of $\dfrac 1 R$ for any two points $\vec{r}_s \in \mathbb{V}_s$ is:
$$\frac{1}{R} - \frac{1}{R+\mathcal{D}} = \frac{\mathcal{D}}{R\left(R+\mathcal{D}\right)} = \frac{1}{R}\cfrac{ \color{red}{\frac{\mathcal{D}}{R}}}{1+\color{red}{\frac{\mathcal{D}}{R}}}$$
Similarly, the maximum possible angle between the values of $\hat{R}$ for any two points $\vec{r}_s \in \mathbb{V}_s$  is:
$$
2\;{\tan}^{-1}\left(\frac12 \color{red} {\frac{\mathcal{D}}{R}}\right)
$$
When $R \gg \mathcal{D}$, $\dfrac {\mathcal{D}} R \approx 0$, and each of the two expressions above are $\approx 0$ as well. So $\dfrac 1 R$ and $\hat{R}$ are essentially independent of $\vec{r}_s$. We can, therefore, bring out all $\dfrac 1 R$ and $\hat{R}$ factors outside the integral sign.

So if I define the following:
$$
W\left(\vec{r},t\right) = 
\iiint_{\mathbb{V}_s} 
\rho \left( \vec{r}_s, t_r \right)
\space dV\left(\vec{r}_s\right)
$$
$$
\vec{Y}\left(\vec{r},t\right) = 
\iiint_{\mathbb{V}_s} 
\vec{J} \left( \vec{r}_s, t_r \right)
\space dV\left(\vec{r}_s\right)
$$
$$
\vec{Z}\left(\vec{r},t\right) = 
\iiint_{\mathbb{V}_s} 
 \frac {\partial \vec{J} \left( \vec{r}_s, t_r \right) } {\partial t}
\space dV\left(\vec{r}_s\right) 
= \frac {\partial \vec{Y}\left(\vec{r},t\right)} {\partial t}
$$
I can then say:
$$
\vec{E}\left(\vec{r},t\right) =
\frac {1} {4 \pi \epsilon_0}
\left[
   \frac {W (\vec{r}, t)} {R^2} \hat{R}
    + \frac {\vec{Y} (\vec{r}, t) \cdot \hat{R}} {R^2 c} \hat{R}
    + \frac {\left(\vec{Y}(\vec{r}, t) \times \hat{R}\right) \times \hat{R}} {R^2 c}
    + \frac {\left(\vec{Z}(\vec{r}, t) \times \hat{R}\right) \times \hat{R}} {R c^2}  
\right]
$$
$$
\vec{B}\left(\vec{r},t\right) =
\frac {\mu_0} {4 \pi}
\left[
    \frac {\vec{Y}  (\vec{r}, t) \times \hat{R}} {R^2}
    + \frac {\vec{Z}(\vec{r}, t) \times \hat{R}} {R c} 
\right]
$$
Applying $\color{blue}{\left(\vec{a} \times \hat{u}\right) \times \hat{u} \equiv \left(\vec{a}\cdot\hat{u}\right)\hat{u} - \vec{a}}$, we can then say:
$$
\vec{E}\left(\vec{r},t\right) =
\frac {1} {4 \pi \epsilon_0} \left[
 \left(
    \frac {W (\vec{r}, t)} {R^2}
    + 2\frac 
      {\vec{Y} (\vec{r}, t) \cdot \hat{R}} 
      {R^2 c}
    + \frac
      {\vec{Z}\left( \vec{r}, t \right)\cdot\hat{R}}
      {R c^2}
   \right) \hat{R}
 - \frac 1 {Rc} \left(
     \frac {\vec{Y} (\vec{r}, t) } {R}
   + \frac {\vec{Z}(\vec{r}, t)} {c} 
  \right)
\right]
$$
$$
\vec{B}\left(\vec{r},t\right) =
\frac {\mu_0} {4 \pi} \left[
\frac 1 R
{\left(
\frac {\vec{Y}  (\vec{r}, t)} {R} +
\frac {\vec{Z}(\vec{r}, t)} {c} \right)}
\times \hat{R}
\right]
$$
Thus, if I define:
$$
\mathcal{U}\left(\vec{r},t\right) = 
 \color{blue}{
  \vec{W} \left(\vec{r},t\right) 
  + \frac {\vec{Y} \left(\vec{r},t\right) \cdot \hat{R}} {c}
 }
 = \iiint_{\mathbb{V}_s} \left[
   \rho \left( \vec{r}_s, t_r \right)
   + \frac { \vec{J} \left( \vec{r}_s, t_r \right) \cdot \hat{R} } {c}
\right] \space dV\left(\vec{r}_s\right)
$$
$$
\vec{\mathcal{X}} \left(\vec{r},t\right) =
  \color{blue}{ 
   \frac {\vec{Y} \left(\vec{r},t\right)} {R} 
   + \frac {\vec{Z} \left(\vec{r},t\right)}  {c}
  }
= \iiint_{\mathbb{V}_s} \left[
   \frac { \vec{J} \left( \vec{r}_s, t_r \right) } {R}
   + \frac 1 c \frac {\partial \vec{J} \left( \vec{r}_s, t_r \right) } {\partial t}
\right] \space dV\left(\vec{r}_s\right)
$$
I get:
$$
\vec{E}\left(\vec{r},t\right) =
\frac {1} {4 \pi \epsilon_0} 
\left[
  \frac {\mathcal{U}\left(\vec{r},t\right)} {R^2} \hat{R}
  + \frac {\left( \vec{\mathcal{X}}\left(\vec{r},t\right) \times \hat{R}\right) \times \hat{R}} {Rc} 
\right]
$$
$$
\vec{B}\left(\vec{r},t\right) =
\frac {\mu_0} {4 \pi} 
\left[
  \frac {\vec{\mathcal{X}} \left(\vec{r},t\right) \times \hat{R}} {R} 
\right]
$$
Finally giving me:
$$
\vec{S}\left(\vec{r},t\right) =
  \mathcal{U} \left(\vec{r},t\right) \frac {\hat{R} \times \left( \vec{\mathcal{X}} \left(\vec{r},t\right) \times \hat{R} \right) } {16 \pi^2 \epsilon_0 R^3}
  + \frac {\left| \vec{\mathcal{X}} \left(\vec{r},t\right) \times \hat{R} \right|^2}  {16 \pi^2 \epsilon_0 R^2 c} \hat{R}
$$
Now my first question is: **Is my math correct so far?**

Now, I define a sphere $\mathbb{V}$ with its center at $\vec{r}_0$ (the center of the source volume $\mathbb{V}_s$.) such that point $\vec{r}$ is on its surface. Then the unit vector $\hat{R}$ will actually be the unit normal $\hat{n}\left(\vec{r}\right)$ at $\vec{r}$.

I want to compute the power passing the surface of $\mathbb{V}$, which should be:
$$
\oint_{\partial\mathbb{V}}
  \vec{S}\left(\vec{r},t\right) \cdot \hat{R}
\;ds\left(\vec{r}\right)
= \frac 1 {16 \pi^2 \epsilon_0 R^2 c} \oint_{\partial\mathbb{V}} \left| \frac {\vec{Y}\left(\vec{r},t\right) \times \hat{R}} {R} + \frac {\vec{Z}\left(\vec{r},t\right) \times \hat{R}} {c} \right|^2 \;ds\left(\vec{r}\right) 
$$

My second question is: **How do I parameterize and compute this surface integral?** I have got to the following expression (it seems to me that when I am integrating over $\vec{r}$, I can still take $\dfrac 1 R$ out from under the integral, but not $\hat{R}$), but I'm stuck after this: $$ \color{blue}{\dfrac {\oint_{\partial\mathbb{V}} \left|\vec{Y}\left(\vec{r},t\right) \times \hat{R}\right|^2 \;ds\left(\vec{r}\right)} {16 \pi^2 \epsilon_0 R^4 c} + \dfrac {\oint_{\partial\mathbb{V}} \left(\vec{Y}\left(\vec{r},t\right) \times \hat{R}\right)\cdot\left(\vec{Z}\left(\vec{r},t\right) \times \hat{R}\right) \;ds\left(\vec{r}\right)} {8 \pi^2 \epsilon_0 R^3 c^2}} \color{red}{+ \dfrac {\oint_{\partial\mathbb{V}} \left|\vec{Z}\left(\vec{r},t\right) \times \hat{R}\right|^2 \;ds\left(\vec{r}\right)} {16 \pi^2 \epsilon_0 R^2 c^3}} $$ I **expected** to prove that the term in $\color{red}{red}$ is independent of $R$, and the term in $\color{blue}{blue}$ is 'reversible', by which I mean if there are two time instants $t_1$ and $t_2$ such that: $$\forall \vec{r}_s \in \mathbb{V}_s:\qquad \rho\left(t_1\right) = \rho\left(t_2\right), \qquad\vec{J}\left(t_1\right) = \vec{J}\left(t_2\right)$$ ... then I hoped to prove that: $$ \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \dfrac {\oint_{\partial\mathbb{V}} \left|\vec{Y}\left(\vec{r},t\right) \times \hat{R}\right|^2 \;ds\left(\vec{r}\right)} {16 \pi^2 \epsilon_0 R^4 c} + \dfrac {\oint_{\partial\mathbb{V}} \left(\vec{Y}\left(\vec{r},t\right) \times \hat{R}\right)\cdot\left(\vec{Z}\left(\vec{r},t\right) \times \hat{R}\right) \;ds\left(\vec{r}\right)} {8 \pi^2 \epsilon_0 R^3 c^2}\;dt = 0$$ ... but so far I have not been able to make any progress. Would appreciate any help...

Comment: $R$ depends on $\vec{r}$, so I don't understand how you can pull it out of the integral.

Comment: @Raskolnikov --  My reasoning is: all $\vec{r}_s$ are in a sphere of diameter $\mathcal{D}$ where $R \gg \mathcal{D}$. So $\frac 1 {\left|\vec{r}-\vec{r}_s\right|} \approx \frac 1 R$ irrespective of $\vec{r}$ as long as $\vec{r} \in \partial \mathbb{V}$ given $\mathbb{V} = B\left(\vec{r}_0, R\right)$. The approximation becomes more exact the larger $R$ gets. So I cannot take $R$ out of the integral, but **can** take $\frac 1 R$.